# user's clicking path

Tags: statistics, analytics, business-intelligence

I'm trying to program some user-behavior-monitoring functionality and it's a bit tricky. For example how do you go about recording a user's clicking path to be used in future analysis? Am I trying to reinvent the wheel? is it easy? is it harder than what I'm thinking?

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional listeners for mouse clicks and insert event and some useful data in DB.
Than you can analyze them.

If you are going to monitor program and you can't change source code, than it's quit hard or maybe impossible.

Answer (score 1):

[ClickHeat](http://www.labsmedia.com/clickheat/index.html) can track clicks and generate heatmaps.

[Freetale](http://dfhu.org/blog/freetale) tracks mouse movements and scrolling and can generate replays ala the commercial ClickTale.

Both of these are open source, so you can find plenty of answers by looking at the source.

Comment: I'm assuming you need to track users on the web. Come to think of it, I wonder if there's anything similar for desktop applications.

Comment: I was indeed asking the question for web. +1 for the useful links.